# What happens to uncertainty in velocity with increase in velocity?

Tags: heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Heisenberg principle states that product of uncertainty in velocity (momentum but assuming mass constant) and uncertainty in position is greater than reduced Planck constant divided by 2. What happens when the system is traveling at a high velocity? Does the uncertainty in velocity increase or decrease with increasing velocity?

Comment: Why don't you try to answer yourself. Hint: the Heisenberg uncertainty principle involves only the variances, not the means.

Comment: Sorry @lcv, I think we were posting simultaneously and did not see your preference for a hint only.

Comment: @ProfM no problem.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: whether the "uncertainty" in the momentum (velocity) increases or decreases (or stays the same) has no connection with the magnitude of the momentum.

Longer commment: I would first like to clarify the word "uncertainty", which is many times misunderstood in the context of Heisenberg's uncertainty principle. The principle states:
$$
\Delta x\Delta p_x\geq\frac{\hbar}{2},
$$
where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p_x$ are respectively referred to as the uncertainty in the position and the uncertainty in the momentum. What they are is the root mean square deviation of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}_x$ with respect to some state $|\psi\rangle$, defined as:
$$
\Delta x=\sqrt{\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle-\langle\hat{x}\rangle^2},
$$
and similarly for $\hat{p}_x$, where the expectation value of an operator $\hat{A}$ with respect to a state $|\phi\rangle$ is defined as $\langle\hat{A}\rangle=\langle\phi|\hat{A}|\phi\rangle$.

What do these root mean square deviations measure? If you were to expand the state of interest $|\psi\rangle$ in the basis of eigenstates of the operator of interest, then the root mean square deviation measures the "spread" in that expansion, something akin to the number of terms in the expansion and their distribution. As a limit of this, for an eigenstate of the operator, then the root mean square deviation is zero.

Going back to your question, if you say that you increase the value of the momentum, you are implicitly assuming that you are in an eigenstate of momentum, and whatever the magnitude of the momentum, the root mean square deviation would always be zero, so it would not change with changes in momentum. In reality, you will probably have a narrow distribution of momenta around a "mean" momentum, and the root mean square deviation will be small but not zero. But in this second more realistic case, it is still true that there is no fundamental reason why the root mean square deviation should increase when you change the momentum. Depending on how you build the new higher momentum state, you *may* change the root mean square deviation, but you may change it in either direction, so no general statement is possible.

This answer applies in a non-relativistic setting.

Comment: are you sure that uncertainty in momentum has no relation with the magnitude of momentum. I think that's true only if you don't consider the relativistic formula for momentum.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @AyushRaj. I have edited my response to specify that this is for non-relativistic QM.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question would be better phrased if it's written this way- Does the uncertainty in velocity increase or decrease with increasing velocity, given that uncertainty in the position is the same at all velocities.

If that is what you mean, then we have the following- Since momentum p=a*m*v, where a is the Lorentz factor, m is the rest mass of the particle, del_p=m*a^3*del_v, in nature's unit where c=1, and hence v<1 (You can do a straightforward calculation to check it). Now assuming minimum uncertainty is achieved at all times, i.e, del_p*del_x=Reduced Planck constant/2 (else there will be no way to compare uncertainties at different velocities), we have that del_v=reduced Plack constant/(2*m*a^3*del_x). So at high velocities, for the same uncertainty in position, del_v is smaller compared to that at low velocities.

If you didn't mean the correction in the question that I suggested, then, well, there's no way to talk about just the uncertainty in velocity if you don't have knowledge of the uncertainty in the position of the particle.

I hope this helps!